# How to add relationships for additional columns in pivot table in Laravel and Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
users
-id
-name

relation_types
-id
-type

user_relation
-user1_id
-user2_id
-relation_type_id
```

In `User` model I have:

```
public function relatedParties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_relation', 'user1_id', 'user2_id')->withPivot('relation_type_id');
    }
```

I can get the `relation_type_id` by `App\User::find(1)->relatedParties[0]->pivot->relation_type_id`.

In order to get `relation type` instead of `id`, I added this relationship in the model of `user_relation` table

```
public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RelationType', 'relation_type_id');
    }
```

but `App\User::find(1)->relatedParties[0]->pivot->type` returns `null`

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this answer [Laravel - Additional relationship on a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673390/7039893)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$user=User::with('relatedParties','relatedParties.type')->first();
foreach($user->relatedParties as $relatedParty)
{
   foreach($relatedParty->type as $type)
   {
         print_r($type->type);
   }
}
```

Comment: I got this `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::type()`. And I think you mean `User::with('relatedParties','relatedParties.type')->find(1);`?

Comment: Isn't type()  the relation in relatedParty model?

Comment: `type()` is in `UserRelation` which is the model for the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access type from pivot table because type is not a column in the proviot table. so your code for access type is giving null for acessing type.

```
App\User::find(1)->relatedParties[0]->pivot->type
```

Again relationship in user_relation table is between relation_types, user_relation table which can not be called in the realtion of users,user_relation.

To get the type of "relation_type_id" just simply get the type from relation_types table as written below.

```
$relationTypeId = \App\User::find(3)->relatedParties[0]->pivot->relation_type_id;
$rtype = \App\RelationType::find($relationTypeId)->pluck('type');
echo $rtype;
```

Comment: According to the [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) `Notice that each Role model we retrieve is automatically assigned a pivot attribute. This attribute contains a model representing the intermediate table, and may be used like any other Eloquent model.`, the `pivot` attribute will contain the model of `user_relation` table. If that's the case`pivot->type` should work, shouldn't it?