# Laravel - Additional relationship on a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a regular pivot table with 2 keys. However, I also have a 3rd column where I want to store a different key with a one to many relationship. Is this possible to have?

Example:

Pivot table:
Organization 1 | Organization 2 | Relation type
1 | 2 | 1
1 | 3 | 2

In this case organization number 1 has a relation with organization number 2 with the relation type being number 1. Organization number 1 also has a relation with organization number 3 with relation type 2.

Now is my question, how do I set up that additional one to many relationship on the pivot table?

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a ternary relationship. You are saying that an organisation A relates with an organisation B and a relationship type. This is a very uncommon use case because in the vast majority of cases ternary relationships can be simplified to binary ones. You need a very deep inspection of your data model to determine whether your case can be simplified, but assuming that it can't here's my suggestions.

It's worth checking [the eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in particular under *Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models* for this. Note that this requires Laravel 5.4+ to work.

The following should work:

```
class OrganisationOrganisationLink extends Pivot {
    public relationType() {
          return $this->belongsTo(RelationType::class); //You need to specify the foreign key correctly as a 2nd parameter
    }
}
```

Then in your original model:

```
class Organisation extends Model {
    public relatedOrganisation() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(self::class)->using(OrganisationOrganisationLink::class); 
    }
}
```

Then when making practical use of this you can e.g. do:

```
$organisation = Organisation::with('relatedOrganisation')->first();
echo "Got ".$organisation->name." which relates to "
     .$organisation->relatedOrganisation->first()->name 
     ." with relationship type "       
     $organisation->relatedOrganisation->first()->pivot->relationshipType()->value('name');
```

Of course the fields I've assumed may not exist but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: hello, do you have any idea of how to preload pivot relationship? I tried with('relatedOrganisation.pivot.relationshipType') and with('relatedOrganisation.relationshipType') without success

Comment: @LucaC. I don't think you can do this using the above pivot. Maybe you can add `protected $with =  [ 'relationshipType' ];` in the pivot model, but that would eager load the relationship every time (if it actually works)